# Create dataframe with specific slices out of existing dataframe, based on date variabels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, columnsorting

I have the following dataframe (df) with a column 'date' and 'values'. I am looking for a solution how to create a new dataframe from the variables start_MM_DD and end_MM_DD (month and day). For each year a column with the corresponding values should be created. the data frame "df" can start earlier or data can be missing, depending on how the variables start.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='2020-01-03', end='2022-01-10')})
df['randNumCol'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, df.shape[0])


start_MM_DD = '01-01'
end_MM_DD = '01-15'
```

the new dataframe should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# create your date range; the year does not matter
d_range = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-01-15').strftime('%m-%d')

# use boolean indexing to filter your frame based on the months and days you want
new = df[df['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d').isin(d_range)].copy()

# get the year from the date column
new['year'] = new['date'].dt.year

# pivot the frame
new['date'] = new['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
print(new.pivot('date', 'year', 'randNumCol'))

year   2020  2021  2022
date                   
01-01   NaN   3.0   5.0
01-02   NaN   4.0   2.0
01-03   2.0   4.0   3.0
01-04   3.0   3.0   3.0
01-05   2.0   2.0   4.0
01-06   5.0   5.0   3.0
01-07   1.0   3.0   3.0
01-08   2.0   5.0   2.0
01-09   2.0   2.0   5.0
01-10   5.0   5.0   2.0
01-11   5.0   5.0   NaN
01-12   2.0   3.0   NaN
01-13   1.0   2.0   NaN
01-14   1.0   3.0   NaN
01-15   4.0   3.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a pivot table that has been filtered by dates:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='2020-01-03', end='2022-01-10')})
df['randNumCol'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, df.shape[0])

df = (
    df.loc[(df['date'].dt.month.eq(1)) & (df['date'].dt.day.between(1,15))]
      .pivot_table(index=df['date'].dt.day,
                   columns=df['date'].dt.year)
).droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None)

print(df)
```

Output

```
date  2020  2021  2022
1      NaN   2.0   1.0
2      NaN   5.0   4.0
3      3.0   1.0   2.0
4      3.0   1.0   2.0
5      4.0   5.0   5.0
6      5.0   1.0   4.0
7      2.0   4.0   2.0
8      4.0   3.0   3.0
9      5.0   5.0   3.0
10     4.0   3.0   3.0
11     1.0   1.0   NaN
12     2.0   2.0   NaN
13     1.0   4.0   NaN
14     3.0   2.0   NaN
15     1.0   3.0   NaN
```

Comment: thank you chris, but if i want to see 01-01 until 06-30? what is missing is the start and end.